# Add more data to series in highchart pie chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to be able to show 'Good' or 'Bad' in a tooltip depending on some data particular to each data in the series.

Right now I have the following:

```
data: [
['Firefox', 1],
['IE', 2],
['Safari', 3],
['Opera', 4],
['Others', 5]
]
```

How could I add another member into that array, for example:

```
['Firefox', 1, 'Good']
```

So that I could reference it in the tooltip such as:

```
 tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.good_or_bad}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this by using tooltip formatter

there are 2 approaches with it

1. use tooltip > formatter with your own validations

   tooltip: {
       formatter : function(){
           //your validations here to decide good or bad
       }
   }
2. pass the addl details with the data point and access it from tool tip

pass the data as shown below
    series:[{
        data: [{
            name: 'FireFox',
            y: 1,
            isGood: 'Good'
         }]
    }]

access it from tooltip as shown below

```
tooltip:{
    formatter: function() {
       this.point.options.isGood
    }
}
```

Hope one of these approaches will give a solution to you